# Can I have concurrent instances of  the async implementation of ping?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, ping

I would like to ping many different hosts simultaniously.  Does .NET handle this concurrency for me, or must I implement this myself?

For example, the following object internally uses the Async version of ping:

```
Mypinger.Tracert("microsoft.com");
```

And I may have a different instance doing the same thing, but to a different host *at the same time*:

```
Mypinger.Tracert("google.com");
```

What prevents the concurrent Async methods from each instance interfering with each other?

What is the limit on the concurrency?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Use the *Async* variants of the various methods on the `Ping` class.

Adapted from the examples in the [Ping class documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx):

```
private void SendPing()
{
    // ...
    Ping pingSender = new Ping();
    pingSender.PingCompleted +=
             new PingCompletedEventHandler(PingCompletedCallback);

    // the async methods don't block,
    // and execution will continue after the following call
    pingSender.SendAsync(address, userToken);
    // ...
}

private void PingCompletedCallback(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    PingReply reply = e.Reply;
    object userToken = e.UserState;
    // ...
}
```

With regards to your edit and comment, although ICMP communication is typically stateless, ECHO messages (used in pings) maintain connection state, and so know what ping requests triggered a given response. There's really no limit on concurrency, excluding connection swamping.

Comment: I'm using the async version, but I'd like to have my multi threaded app ping microsoft, while the other pings google, at the same time. I don't want the pings to get confused between the instances. In otherwords, is there a link between the packet on the wire and each (new) instance of ping?